# Inter- and intra-individual biologic variation in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have data (blood glucose values) on 10 subjects measured every 2 weeks for 12 weeks (so 6 data points per subject).  The goal is to calculate coefficients of variation for between-patient variation and within-patient variation, i.e. partition into that due to differences between subjects vs. that due to differences in a given subject measured at different timepoints.

For the purposes of this study, analytic variation is not considered.  Variables are `subjectID`, `week`, and `glucose`.

It looks like the `lme4` package is the most appropriate, but I have no familiarity with it.  Would the following be correct?

```
model <- lme4::lmer(glucose ~ week + (1|subjectID), data=BloodGlucose)
```

Comment: You are being downvoted because you don't provide any example here. You should provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. data on which it is possible to test your regression method and offer new solution

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear at all what you mean by coefficient of variation for between patient variation.

What `lmer (glucose ~ week + (1|subjectID), data=BloodGlucose)` will give you is a slope/variation coefficient predicting you glucose in function of week, and `(1|subjectID)` will allow the intercept of that slope to vary for each subject.

It seems to me that what you want is to know the variation of the slope coefficient between each patient. In this case you would need to write

```
lmer (glucose ~ week + (1+week|subjectID), data=BloodGlucose)
```

You will have the mean coefficient giving the variation of glucose function of week and its variation between subject.

Further help would need you to provide a proper example with usable data